# Rolling multiple rows into single row

Tags: ms-access

I need help getting multiple rows of data to all pull into one row based on a primary key. I have four teachers rating a student's academic and behavior performance through the year. At the end of the year, I'll have one spreadsheet per grade that's going to look something like this:

```
ID   First   Last   Subj   ARate   Expl              BRate   Expl
--   -----   ----   ----   -----   ---------------   -----   ---------------
345  Kris    Bell   Eng    5                         3       Talks a lot
345  Kris    Bell   Math   3       0% on EQ test     2       Disruptive
345  Kris    Bell   Sci    4                         4       
345  Kris    Bell   SS     2       Failed 2 tests    4
286  Manny   Joy    Eng    5                         5
286  Manny   Joy    Math   4                         5
...
```

I want to create one table that compiles all 4 rows into one row. Something like this:

```
ID   First   Last   Eng_A   Expl              Eng_B   Expl             Math_A   Expl              Math_B   
--   -----   ----   ----    ---------------   -----   ---------------  ------   ---------------   -----
345  Kris    Bell   5                         3       Talks a lot      3        0% on EQ test     2
286  Manny   Joy    5                         5                        4                          4
...
```

There will be separate columns for each subject with explanations if applicable-- I just didn't have room to include all four subjects in this StackExchange question. I have ideas about how to do this in Excel, but I also know some SQL so I'd like to learn how to use Access to do this. I thought about creating a database with one table per grade, then creating one table that pulls a one-to-one relation from each subject. Could I write some SQL code to do this? Is there an easier way besides one-to-one joining?

Comment: Its called pivot and you can use a case expression like case when subj = 'Eng' then arate end as eng_a